# Extracting first non-dot string of text after the last backslash

Tags: regex, powershell

can someone kindly help me extract bold text "england" from the supplied string below

`\ABCD\E$\FGHI$\BAB-COM-DEP_XYZ\TAM\england.CLSM.IST`

I tried `\\.*?\.` but then i get

`\ABCD\E$\FGHI$\BAB-COM-DEP_XYZ\TAM\england.`

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is the programming language? Please add the relevant code.

Comment: it is powershell, and i am just trying to get the substring out from the bigger string to use in another place

Comment: Ok, so my approach works. But there is a better one. I added a non-regex solution at the top of the answer.

Comment: I added a 4th solution, `$s -replace '.*\\([^\\.]+)[^\\]*$', '$1'`,in case you need the required string "immediately" without referring to `$matches[n]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Powershell, you may get the file name without extension, split the string with `.` and grab the first ite:

```
PS> $s = '\ABCD\E$\FGHI$\BAB-COM-DEP_XYZ\TAM\england.CLSM.IST'
PS> [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($s).Split('.')[0]
england
```

If you need a regex for whatever reason, I suggest using

```
.*\\([^.]+)
```

and grab Group 1 value. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bBLu0f/1).

**Details**

- `.*\\` - match all text up to and including the last `\` char (since `.*` is a greedy subpattern)
- `([^.]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `.`

An alternative regex can look like

```
([^.\\]+)[^\\]*$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bBLu0f/2).

**Details**

- `([^.\\]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `.` and `\`
- `[^\\]*$` - 0 or more chars other than `\` up to the end of the string (`$`).

**Powershell usage**:

```
PS> $s -match '([^.\\]+)[^\\]*$' | Out-Null
PS> $matches[1]
england
```

**If you need a regex that will return the required string directly**, you may use

```
 $s -replace '.*\\([^\\.]+)[^\\]*$', '$1'
```

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*%5c%5c%28%5b%5e%5c%5c.%5d%2b%29%5b%5e%5c%5c%5d*%24&i=%5cABCD%5cE%24%5cFGHI%24%5cBAB-COM-DEP_XYZ%5cTAM%5cengland.CLSM.IST&r=%241)

- `.*` - match any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `\\` - a `\` char
- `([^\\.]+)` - Group 1 (referenced with `$1`): matches and consumes one or more chars other than `\` and `.`
- `[^\\]*$` - 0+ chars other than `\` (`[^\\]*`) and end of string (`$`).

Comment: sorry for the trouble but how do i modify it to give result as "england.CLSM". i realized i'll need both strings to work on. so i mean to drop everything till england, then capture all till CLSM and ignore the rest

Comment: @RohitKachroo Perhaps, `$s -replace '.*\\([^\\.]+\.[^\\.]+)[^\\]*$', '$1'`. Alternatively, `$s -match '([^.\\]+\.[^.\\]+)[^\\]*$' | Out-Null`, and `$matches[1]`.

Comment: you are awesome, works like a charm. Thanks a lot. Could you please demonstrate a bit how you achieved this

Comment: @RohitKachroo Sorry, achieved what? What do you mean by demonstrate? A demo? [Here is one](https://regex101.com/r/bBLu0f/3).

Comment: perfect, appreciated , demo is exactly what i asked for

Comment: if the format won't really change at all can this not be done easier with a non-greedy match to grab the 3 segments? i.e. `-replace ".+\\(.+?)\.(.+?)\.(.*)",'$1.$2'`

Comment: @colsw There are a lot of ways to do it if the format is the same, I would not even recommend a regex in this case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah i'd reccomend a builtin here as well, was just trying to understand the reasoning behind your Regex, I'm not amazing at Regex myself so when I see people with more knowledge in it I usually ask some questions.

Comment: @colsw You needn't define additional capturing groups that you do not use later. It is redundant overhead. I'd use `-replace '.+\\([^.]+)\.([^.]+).*','$1.$2'` then.

Answer (score 0):

Use a look behind for a slash and negative look ahead for other slashes:

```
(?<=\\)[^\\.]+(?!.*\\)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/yaYBqFDU5T).

Note there are no groups; the whole match is your target!

Comment: Thanks to you too for the answer